# mockRespond method inside beforeEach invokes later than XHR to backend inside test

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine

I am trying to write Jasmine tests using MockBackend from Angular2.

Here is the code that I write to test a service which communicate with backend:

```js
import { inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import {VehicleCategoryService} from './VehicleCategoryService';

import { BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import {HttpService} from "../../api/HttpService";
import {ApplicationService} from "../../api/ApplicationService";

describe('VehicleCategoryService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [VehicleCategoryService,BaseRequestOptions, MockBackend, ApplicationService, {
        provide: HttpService,
        useFactory: (backend, options, applicationService) => {
          return new HttpService(backend, options, applicationService);
        },
        deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions, ApplicationService],
      }],
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([MockBackend], (backend: MockBackend) => {
    const baseResponse = new Response(new ResponseOptions({ body: '{"Name":"MiniVan"}' }));
    backend.connections.subscribe((c: MockConnection) => c.mockRespond(baseResponse));
  }));

  it('should be defined', inject([VehicleCategoryService], (vehicleCategoryService: VehicleCategoryService) => {
    expect(vehicleCategoryService).toBeDefined();
  }));

  it('should return response when querying vehicleCategories', inject([VehicleCategoryService], (vehicleCategoryService: VehicleCategoryService) => {
    vehicleCategoryService.query().subscribe((res: Response) => {
      expect(res['Name']).toBe('MiniVan');
    });
  }));
});
```

```html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

HttpService here is a service that extends from built-in Http Angular2 service. query() method returns Observable as a usual Http do.
Debugging issue demonstarte that mockRespond() method inside subscription invokes later than actual call to backend that is why I receive undefined response. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Update: I noticed that subscription inside beforeEach is executing later then http service method triggered. So behaviour is understandable, but how can I fix it without timeouts.

Comment: Not sure why this is happening, but you can get the backend in the first beforeEach. `TestBed.get(MockBackend)`. See if that makes any difference

Comment: Actually -- _"Debugging issue demonstarte that mockRespond() method inside subscription invokes later than actual call to backend"_ - This is _supposed_ to happen. You need to make the request, then the backend receives the connection, then calls all subscribers to the connections.

Comment: Also in your test, you are trying to get a `Name` Property in the `Response`. I don't think that's correct. Either you have the wrong type (it should not be Response) or you need to map it first

Comment: Ok, if it supposed to happen why do I receive undefined as a response? TestBed.get(MockBackend) does not help.

Comment: I don't know. But another thing: you are trying to test this synchronously. It needs to be tested _asynchronously_. Maybe that is the problem. You should wrap the test in `async(inject(....`

Comment: Do I need to use done() together with async or wrapping is enough?

Comment: No you don't need to use done. You could use it _instead of_ async if you wanted

Comment: wrapping in async does not help( no ideas more.

Comment: I understand that entering mockRespond is happening only when we trying to make XHR call but still response in undefined and it is an issue(